# changing background-image using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I wanted to change my background using ruby, but the background is  white

```
body {
  background: url(<%= asset_path'#{@imagefond}'%>) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

in my `fils.rb`, I put,

```
def background_acceuil
  i=0
  t=['fond.jpg','fond1.jpg']
  while i<t.length
    @imagefond=t[i]
    sleep 3
    i=i+1
    if i==t.length
    i=0
  end
end
```

Comment: which version of rails you are using ? Please edit tags according to that.

Comment: i'm  using version 4.2.6

Comment: Are you getting any error ? You want to use two different images as background please add more explanation for better understanding

Comment: i want to change the backgroung image for "body and body:before" every 3 seconds.

Comment: so if you do inspect element for body tag what It shows in background: url path?

Comment: Not sure if you can achieve that with rails and css. Once you compile the assets I do not think you can change the background once the assets render. Maybe try doing it with JS?